# In Clojure, instead of providing a path, I want to use a string with the contents of a file

Tags: clojure, io

I'm currently writing a restful API and need to receive whole files as string.
I didn't write the actual functions which parse those files and must somehow feed these strings into functions which except a path.

So, what I want to find/build is a function which would solve this Problem:

```
(slurp (INSERT-MAGIC-HERE "The content of my file."))
```

EDIT:

While both answers seemed to work, the most reliable thing I found was to use "char-array". This prevents any error about the stream being closed which I got quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slurp` uses a very flexible mechanism to figure out how to understand its input arguments: it certainly doesn't insist that they be a file. For example, it will accept a java.io.Reader. And it is easy to build a Reader from a String, simply by constructing a StringReader. So,

```
(slurp (java.io.StringReader. "The content of my file."))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to write to the file system, a handy way is to use `java.io.File/createTempFile`.  See

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html

Another, easier option [is to use `tupelo.string/string->stream`](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.string.html#var-string-.3Estream) from the [Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  It was built for just this purpose:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.string :as ts] )) 

(dotest
  (is= "Hello World!"
    (slurp
      (ts/string->stream "Hello World!"))) )
```

Add the following to your `project.clj` file:

```
 [tupelo "0.9.152"]
```

Comment: Note that if your service is running for a long period of time or receives lots of requests, creating temporary files might not be advised because you can hit a limit on the number of open files, or fill the disk because temporary files need to be registered for deletion with `deleteOnExit` and they are removed only when the JVM exits. If you need to call APIs that expect files, I'd advise to remove the files manually once you are done with the API call.